# Can i use django raw on query list

Tags: python, django

I just want to know that just like we can apply filters on query list as many times.

Can i apply raw sql on query list like this

`models.Burn.active.filter(some filter).raw('custom sql')`

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. You can only call [`raw` on `manager` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries).

Since `filter` returns a new `QuerySet`, you will not be able to call `raw` on it.